# Flickr photos by group with location name

Tags: flickr

I am grabbing photos from my 2 flickr groups using the API method flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos. This is ok but i'd like to actually return the town name rather than just the geo location. Does anybody know of an alternative method to grab my images including the geo location, town name, and the group that they are in? I'd rather not make multiple API calls per image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it appears there is no way of doing this. I had to call flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos then flickr.photos.geo.getLocation on each image to get its location. Not the best solution but it is then being cached into a db for improved performance, then only called once every 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can get location attributes by adding "geo" parameter to **extras** argument for **flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos** request.

> extras (Optional)
>   A comma-delimited list of extra information to fetch for each returned record. Currently supported fields are: description, license, date_upload, date_taken, owner_name, icon_server, original_format, last_update, geo, tags, machine_tags, o_dims, views, media, path_alias, url_sq, url_t, url_s, url_q, url_m, url_n, url_z, url_c, url_l, url_o

In response you will receive geo latitude and longitude for each photo from group.